# How do I use Cmdkey.exe /list powershell script to report on microsoft account licenses within Office apps?

Tags: windows, powershell, credentials

We're trying to only report on the following information after running this powershell script.

"LegacyGeneric:target:MicrosoftAccount:user="

```
cmdkey.exe /list | ForEach-Object {$found=$false} {
    $line = $_.Trim()
    if ($line -eq '') 
    {
        if ($found) { $newobject }
        $found = $false
        $newobject = '' | Select-Object -Property Type, User, Info, Target
    }
    else
    {
        if ($line.StartsWith("Target: "))
        {
            $found = $true
            $newobject.Target = $line.Substring(8)
        }
        elseif ($line.StartsWith("Type: "))
        {
            $newobject.Type = $line.Substring(6)
        }
        elseif ($line.StartsWith("User: "))
        {
            $newobject.User = $line.Substring(6)
        }
        else
        {
            $newobject.Info = $line
        }

    }
}
```

The idea behind is it to only get the Microsoft account that Microsoft Office applications are using to obtain their licenses, shown here.

[Credential Manager example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeW1b.jpg)

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help out!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if ours are different or if you have a typo. You list `LegacyGeneric:target:MicrosoftAccount:user=` but I only see `LegacyGeneric:target=MicrosoftAccount:user=`

Please modify it if mine is just different. If you are just wanting the account, you could use something like this.

```
cmdkey /list | foreach {
    if($_ -match 'LegacyGeneric:target=MicrosoftAccount:user=(.*)')
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{Account = $matches.1}
    }
}
```

Output for me looked like

```
Account            
-------            
username1@email.com
username2@email.com
```

If you wanted a one-liner it could do that too.

```
[PSCustomObject]@{Account = $(cmdkey /list | foreach {if($_ -match 'LegacyGeneric:target=MicrosoftAccount:user=(.*)'){$matches.1}})}
```